# Jest Testing onTouchStart/onTouchEnd

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I've got a component that uses the `onTouchStart` and `onTouchEnd` and I can't figure out how to test it.

Here's [a snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@atb-brown/ashamed-soylent) for the code, but the snippet is below:

```js
export default function TouchComponent({
  children,
  onStart = doNothing,
  onEnd = doNothing
}: TouchComponentProps): React.ReactElement {

  return (
    <View
      onTouchStart={(e) => onStart()}
      onTouchEnd={(e) => onEnd()}
    >{children}</View>
  );
}

const doNothing = () => {};

interface TouchComponentProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  onStart?: () => void;
  onEnd?: () => void;
}
```

Looking at the documentation, there aren't any methods listed for `onTouchStart`/`onTouchEnd`, but [this method array](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api/#fireeventeventname) *seems* to suggest that it has other methods that can be invoked, but it doesn't look like it works here because `fireEvent["onTouchStart"](myComponent);` fails with an error saying: `TypeError: _reactNative.fireEvent.onTouchStart is not a function`.

I've searched around but can't seem to find any documentation or other questions about testing `onTouchStart` and `onTouchEnd`, so how do I fire these events?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out almost immediately after asking this question. In my situation, I can invoke them like this:

```js
import TouchComponent from "../TouchComponent ";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react-native";

it("Invokes onTouchStart and onTouchEnd", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <TouchComponent
      onStart={() => {
        console.log("onTouchStart invoked");
      }}
      onEnd={() => {
        console.log("onTouchEnd invoked");
      }}
      testID="my-component" />);
  const myComponent = getByTestId("my-component");

  // Passing empty {} data, but may need to supply for other use cases.
  fireEvent(myComponent, "onTouchStart", {});
  fireEvent(myComponent, "onTouchEnd", {};
});

// Console:
//   console.log
//     onTouchStart invoked
//   console.log
//     onTouchEnd invoked
```